# Animation render creating black image files

Tags: animation

I have just completed my first large project and have a camera fly through the scene. I started rendering the animation to .png files as there were quite a few but after several hours I had to pause it to do something else. When I try to start again from the next image file and render the animation, all I get is a series of place holder files with nothing on them. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please upload you blend file somewhere or at least show us some screenshots of your settings?

Comment: Upload your model on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add some image of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I realised what I had done. I had created a video file with what I had and then forgot to delete it from video editor. Once I did that it works fine.